# Should my component which has an IDisposable constructor dependency be IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

Here's my class:

```
public class TaskLogger : ITaskLogger
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;

    public TaskLogger(IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        _dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }

    public void LogTask(int clientId, string taskName)
    {
        _dbConnection.Execute("insert blah",{clientId,taskName}});
    }
}
```

We use Windsor for DI.

Should TaskLogger be declared IDisposable, and dispose the IDbConnection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Since the instance is passed to your class from the caller, the caller is responsible for disposing it. This is because your class should not assume it is the only consumer of this instance - there might be another class that uses the same connection but lives longer than your `TaskLogger` instance.

Your class should dispose the instances it creates itself.

Another approach would be to add a constructor `public TaskLogger(IDbConnection dbConnection, bool closeConnection)` and dispose the connection when the value passed in is `true`. This approach is used by [some `System.IO` classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952.aspx) (although they do it the other way around and use `leaveOpen` - but for streams it is a different story because usually a stream will not be used by multiple instances at the same time).

Comment: Agreed, although I must point out that there are classes in the .Net CLR which dispose the item passed to a constructor, for example [`BinaryReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k01zeat.aspx) (Which I always thought was a bad idea!)

Comment: Yes, I think your first sentence says it - a class it not responsible for the the lifecycle of injected dependencies. I was looking for some confirmation that it all 'just works' in Windsor. Because on this approach we are assuming that the DI container is responsible and will in fact deal with it

Comment: When using DI you should not dispose instances you don't own even more - because the main idea is that the framework controls how those instances are used. For example, the connection might be a singleton but the logger per thread... Because of this DI framework will handle the disposal.

Comment: You could even go one step further and say that if you are using Windsor to Resolve() then you should probably not use Dispose() anyway, you should use Release(). If a component implements IDisposable, Windsor will ensure that Dispose() is called at the appropriate time. E.g. By calling Dispose() yourself you are hard-coding assumptions about component lifetime that ideally should be controlled by registration/configuration. The simple rule of "Release everything you Resolve" always seems to work well for me with Windsor.